# Reduce degree of a high degree unconstrained binary term to quadratic unconstrained binary term

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

I'm working on a optimization project, in this project I have to convert higher order unconstrained binary polynomial to quadratic unconstrained binary polynomial. Can anyone give me a hint of how to do it?

For example:

> I want to convert ${ x }_{ 1 }{ x }_{ 2 }{ x }_{ 3 }$ into quadratic unconstrained term:
>
> $\sum _{ i,j\quad \in \quad poly }^{ \quad  }{ { J }_{ij}{ x }_{ i }{ x }_{ j } } $

In order to do this, in my understanding, I should introduce penalty terms to force auxiliary variable build connections for quadratic terms, some thing like:

> Corresponding quadratic term:
>
> $f\left( x \right) =\sum _{ i,j\quad \in \quad poly }^{ \quad  }{ { J }_{ij}{ x }_{ i }{ x }_{ j } } +\gimel \overrightarrow { PE } $
>
> $\overrightarrow { PE } $ is constrains vector, $\gimel$ is penalty factor.

I should calculate $\overrightarrow { PE } $ and $\gimel$.

Is my idea correct? Can anyone give me some advices of how to reduce degree of a polynomial?

Thanks

Comment: And you want the whole model, including the penalties, to be quadratic?

Comment: Hi Johan, yes, the penalties has to be quadratic as well.

Comment: I would be very surprised if an unconstrained binary quadratic model of a polynomial binary problem exist. Proof by lack of imagination does not count though...

Comment: I think it exist. If its a binary unconstrained polynomial, we only need to introduce penalty and award terms to "make up" the consistency (like linear programming). And use the same idea to creat quadratic penalty and awards

Comment: Yes, but $x_1x_2x_3$ would be $x_1x_4+p(x_4-x_2x_3)$. Hence, to not have anything beyond quadratic, the penalty $p()$ would have to be linear. Not a proof, just my lack of imagination.

Comment: yeah, i agree. and we have to introduce new variables

Comment: You absolutely have to introduce new variables, there is no way around that. My concern was whether you could obtain a high-dimensional quadratic to represent a low-dimensional polynomial. I believe not but would be happy to be proven wrong. If you allow linear constraints, the problem is easy.

Comment: I am happy to announce I was wrong. Google "Quadratization of Pseudo-Boolean Functions" and you will find a wealth of material. Always fun to learn new things.

Comment: I'll do that thank you!